# Как округлить число вверх, до ближайшего значения кратного данному шагу?

Tags: java, математика

Допустим есть число 1,73. Как его округлить до большего числа таким образом, чтобы оно стало кратным числу 0,3 ? То есть получить, в данном примере, 1,8.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Делите число на 0,3. Округляйте до большего целого. Умножайте на 0,3. Проверяем:

```
1,73 / 0,3 = 5,76
ceil(5,76) = 6
6 * 0.3 = 1.8
```

---

Можно выполнить целочисленное деление, и если остаток больше 0, то добавить `0,3 - остаток` к исходному числу. Проверка на 0 нужна, чтобы не округлить, например, 1,5 вверх до 1,8. Проверяем:

```
1,73 % 0,3 = 0,23
0,23 != 0.0
0,3 - 0,23 = 0,07
1,73 + 0,07 = 1,8
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь)